# Can't get resized image to save at new size

Tags: objective-c, image, file, resize, save

I have the following code

```
       if (! [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
            // handle error
        }
        else if (! [isValidDirectory boolValue]) {
            // No error and it’s not a directory; do something with the file
            NSString* outP = [url absoluteString];
            NSString* extension = [outP substringFromIndex: outP.length-3];
            NSString* img = @"png";
            if([extension isEqualToString:img]){
                NSImage *original = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
                NSSize sizes = NSMakeSize(240, 240);
                NSImage *small =original;
                [small setSize:sizes];
                NSArray*  representations  = [small representations];
                NSInteger* total = [substrings count];
                NSData* bitmapData = [NSBitmapImageRep representationOfImageRepsInArray: representations usingType: NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
                [bitmapData writeToFile:@"/Users/testuser/downloads/test/test_tn.png" atomically:NO];
           }
```

when I run it it does not resize the image it just gives me a straight copy of the image with the name test_tn.png instead of a smaller image. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, this is a mac app also. There is some unused code in there that is for later. Is the problem how I'm passing the NSImage to the NSData after i resize?

edit: ok so i converted the NSData back into an NSImage and it appears the NSData is not getting the sized data but the original data.

edit 2: so this works

ok so this works

```
            if([extension isEqualToString:img]){
                NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
                NSData *sourcedata =[image TIFFRepresentation];
                NSSize newSize;
                newSize.height = 160;
                newSize.width = 120;
                NSImage *sourceImage =[[NSImage alloc] initWithData: sourcedata];
                NSImage *resizedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: NSMakeSize(240, 240)];

                NSSize originalSize = [sourceImage size];

                [resizedImage lockFocus];
                [sourceImage drawInRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 240, 240) fromRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, originalSize.width, originalSize.height) operation: NSCompositeSourceOver fraction: 1.0];
                [resizedImage unlockFocus];

                NSData *resizedData = [resizedImage TIFFRepresentation];

                NSData *resizedPreviewData = [resizedImage TIFFRepresentation];
                NSBitmapImageRep *resizedCaptureImageBitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:resizedPreviewData];
                NSData* saveData = [resizedCaptureImageBitmapRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
                [saveData writeToFile:@"/Users/testuser/downloads/test/test_tn.png" atomically:YES];
                count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  I am using this code to layer images on top of each other, but it should be easily adapted to your purposes:

```
CGSize destinationSize = smallSize;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(original.size);
[Original1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, original.size.width, original.size.height)];
[Original2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, original.size.width, original.size.height)];

UIImage *returnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
[returnImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you code is doing. is it just doing the resizing? also what are original 1 and 2?

Comment: also how do Import UIImage in a mac app